# Who created the Multidimensional Transporter Device?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-transporter, mirror-universe

In [Through the Looking Glass](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Through_the_Looking_Glass_(episode)), we see the first use of the Multidimensional Transporter Device (MTD), when Smiley kidnaps Sisko to bring him to the mirror universe.

We see the device again when Jennifer kidnaps Jake, and leaves an MTD for Sisko.

In The Emperor's New Cloak, Rom states he was given the schematics of the MTD to study.

Who was responsible for creating the device? Was it an unnamed engineer in the mirror universe? How was Rom able to acquire the schematics?

I **assume** when plugged into the transporter, the DS9 computers are sophisticated enough to understand when a device is plugged in (much like when you plug a USB device into your computer), and provide a detailed analysis of the inner workings of the device, which Starfleet was able to copy and study.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the EU novel [DS9: Warpath](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Warpath), the multi-dimensional transport was designed by Smiley O'Brien, presumably using a mixture of info gleaned from reports about James Kirk's travel to the mirror universe, his own knowledge of transporter technology and scans of the technique used by Kira and Bashir to return to their own universe at the end of *DS9: Crossover*

> The compliment made him pause. “Thank you, Intendant.”
>
> If only that fool Smiley could see what I’ve made of **his little toy**,
> she thought. What a pity he won’t live long enough to witness its true
> power.

This is confirmed in the [*Official Star Trek Fact File #59*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Fact_Files)

> One of the greatest problems faced by the Terrans in retrieving Sisko
> from Deep Space Nine is in recreating the transporter malfunction that
> allows travel between the realities. **Miles 'Smiley' O'Brien of the
> mirror universe is at first reluctant to help Kira Nerys and Bashir to
> escape from his world, but later develops a remote transporter unit
> that can duplicate exactly the effect on a Cardassian-designed
> transporter as the two previous accidental set of circumstances.** In
> addition to this complex engineering, the remote transporter unit
> negates the need for an operator on either side of the universes'
> divide to initiate transportation of one or more individuals, thus
> allowing the user to act with a great deal of flexibility.

---

As to how Rom got the schematics, that's pretty simple to answer. He was given them by Chief O'Brien...

> **ROM:** *My engineering notebook?* (realizing) *With the schematics for the multi-dimensional transporter **that Chief O'Brien gave me to study.*** (a beat) *You stole it...*
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: The Emperor's New Cloak - Original Screenplay](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/562.txt)</sup></sub>

... , who presumably scanned the device that was left for Captain Sisko by (alt)Jennifer Sisko in *DS9: Shattered Mirror* a couple of seasons earlier.

> Sisko, O'BRIEN, Kira and DAX are gathered around the Ops table. **O'Brien is evaluating the (TECH) device Jennifer left Sisko. He's opened a small panel on the device and is poking its innards.**
>
> **O'BRIEN:** *You're sure this is what Smiley used to transport you to the alternate universe?*
>
> **SISKO:** *Looks like it.*
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: Shattered Mirror - Original Screenplay](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/492.txt)</sup></sub>